# How to Upload two files from same page using Java Servlet and JSP with other fields ?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, file-upload, field

I want to upload file along with many other file. and two files from one form. my projects requires photo and resume on same time. so i need to upload both file from same page. can any bdy help me for doing this.

Comment: The concept for one or many files remains same : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=fileupload+jsp&oq=fileupload+jsp&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.1938j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Use following code on your jsp page:

```
<form action="./uploadFile" method="post" >
    <input type="file" name="photo" size="50" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="resume" size="50" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

This code will allow you to upload two files from one form. Fore more details you can also refer following link:

- [Creating a File Upload Form:](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm)

Above code will display following output:

[image: fileupload output]